# Detect Universal App at Runtime in PCL

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, win-universal-app, portable-class-library, windows-10-universal

Is there any way to detect that a main application is a Universal App (W10) from a Portable Class Library?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to detect this in the PCL code?

Comment: I need to detect this because of the following bug in HttpClient : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6946.

If I know W10 UAP is running the code, I can circumvent this bug by modifying the query on the go.

Comment: There is no point at all on relying on an oracle when the app itself can very easily tell you.  Expose a property setter or a constructor argument.  Or just wait until this stabilizes a bit, UWP is still beta quality software and not exactly something you'd want to send out in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box I do not think the functionality you are asking for is available in PCL, but here is a suggestion involving reflection that you might want to try.

It is adapted to the PCL Profile (328) you are using, involving .NET 4 and Silverlight 5. The `GetPlatformName` method needs to be somewhat adjusted if you want to for example switch to PCL profiles 111 and 259, since these profiles would have to rely on `TypeInfo` rather than `Type`.

Here is the proposed method and accompanying interface, which can be implemented in the Portable Class Library:

```
public static class RuntimeEnvironment
{
    public static string GetPlatformName()
    {
        var callingAssembly = (Assembly)typeof(Assembly).GetMethod("GetCallingAssembly").Invoke(null, new object[0]);
        var type = callingAssembly.GetTypes().Single(t => typeof(IPlatform).IsAssignableFrom(t));
        var instance = (IPlatform)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        return instance.PlatformName;
    }
}

public interface IPlatform
{
    string PlatformName { get; }
}
```

Apart from the above code, you will also need to implement the `IPlatform` interface in each platform-specific application, for example like this:

```
public class UniversalPlatform : IPlatform
{
    public string PlatformName => "UWP";
}
```

In short, the `GetPlatformName` method instantiates the single class implementing the `IPlatform` interface in the calling (application) assembly, and returns the `PlatformName` property.

The `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` method is not publicly exposed in any of the PCL profiles, but it is generally implemented and can therefore be accessed via reflection.

The `GetPlatformName` method is fully portable and can thus be consumed within the Portable Class Library itself, allowing you to make platform conditional decisions within the PCL code. The proposal does require minimal code efforts within each platform-specific application, since you do need to implement `IPlatform`, but maybe that is an acceptable price to pay?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways:
first:

1. add PCL to main project (reference)
2. create `enum` in PCL for determine type of OS (for ex. `OperationSystemType`)
3. In main point (start) - for UWP it is `App.cs` pass right value to PCL

second (more flexible):

1. Crete interface `IApplicationProvider` in any PCL
2. Create implementation for each platform (in main project). You can add `OSType` property in interface (for ex.)
3. Bind interface to implementation by IoC container in main project (`App.cs`)
4. Get by IoC instance for interface and get right value

Comment: Thank you Nikita, but I want to detect the UAP compared to have a user explicitly tell the library that the application is running in UAP.

The simple reason is that it is a public library and I do not want (if possible) to have people "configure" the library. In the library it is already possible to do the solution 1, but I'd like to know if it is possible to automate this.

Comment: Which platforms supports your PCL?

Comment: .NET Framework 4 - Windows 8 - Windows Phone SilverLight 8 - Silverlight 5 - Windows Phone 8.1.

It is properly working on Linux, Android, iOS, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows 7,8,10, Rasbery Pi.

Comment: It is big list ... and so different platforms
I think you can't determine platform type in PCL :(

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect a platform from within a PCL is to try and load a type at runtime that is only available for that platform.

For example, for UWP, you could try to load type `Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo`, which is only available in a Windows 10 UWP application:

```
var win10Type = Type.GetType("Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo, Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");

var isWin10UWP = win10Type != null;
```

It's not pretty, but it does work and the technique can be used to detect other platforms as well.