# pcl needs specific implementation of a class (in platform specific project)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I got the following situation:

In a pcl I have an interface `IFoo`
The pcl itself does not contain an implementation of the interface. 
The class (`Foo`) is located in another project with a specific implementation.

However the pcl does need to create an instance of a class with the interface.

How do I best go about this? Or where can I find some example of how this is done.

Comment: Create a second interface (i.e. `IFooFactory`) with a method `Create` that returns an instance of `IFoo`.  All you need to do is accept a parameter of your new interface (`IFooFactory`) and you can safely call its `Create` method.

Comment: but the pcl doesn't know the class exists, so how would this help?

Comment: You're right, the PCL has no idea what `Foo` is, which is why you have to add a parameter to the methods in your PCL that accept an instance of `IFooFactory`.  Your caller will need to provide an instance of the factory, which will have a `Create` method.  The only thing your PCL needs to know is that the `IFooFactory.Create` method returns an instance that is compatible with type `IFoo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joshua Shearer's provided the answer in his comment.

Comment: If you want a solution that automatically invokes an existing implementation from another DLL, you might be inspired by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36087088/650012) answer to a similar question.